# Please give me some advice, he doesn't listen to his teachers and always running around in school

Tags: discipline

Hello my son is 5 year's old and just started Primary School with a July birthday he is one of the youngest, it break's my heart to say he is being very naughty at school, he was a angel in Foundation which is a year before, he has got into the wrong crowd and is being naughty by always running a round and not listening to his teachers, and even breaking things, I've put it down to the friends he has made, they always made the decisions on what they do ( my son is a follower) but today he was the one who was making the decisions because the naughtiest one was suspended, I punish him after punishing him and he just doesn't listen, he tells me what I want to hear says he won't do it again, but always does, what do I do it is now effecting his education and being labelled as a naughty child

Comment: Please include your question in the question title, not just in the body of the question.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. "Please give me some advice" is a very broad question; it's too broad for this site. Have you spoken to the teachers? What have they advised? Please edit to add detail and ask a specific question (e.g. "How do I approach his behavior with his teachers?") or this will be closed as too broad. Thanks.

Comment: He sounds to me like a normal 5 year old boy. I'll keep my rant to myself about this generation of teachers not being able to handle boys because schools of education no longer deal with real children.

Comment: This could be a good question, but not in its current form. "Naughty" is a vague value judgement. There is not enough detail about the specific infractions for us to guess at your child's motivations and triggers. Also, there is no information about the punishments you inflicted, so we can't tell if what you are trying should be helpful or not.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, 5 years old is very young to start school. There are probably children who can handle school with 5 years, but in my opinion this is the minority. Hence, your son's behaviour may be caused by the stress he has to handle being this young and going to school.

In contrast to the time before school, he now has to sit still for around an hour, be creative, be silent, pay attention, be social, be polite and respectful. All at the same time! Wow! This is quite a lot for a 5 year old boy - especially all of a sudden. Don't you think?

So, given all these things that are demanded from your son now, he somehow tries to compensate this, to express himself, to get relieve. In my opinion (and I am no professional but only a stranger from the internet), your son is under tension. Remember, that young children do not have the social skills to express themselves as YOU may expect. You have your perspective of the world and how a person should behave when it has problems. But your son probably does NOT know that or has another opinion on how a person with problems should behave!

The worst thing you can do is punish him (in any way)! You just tell him with this punishment: "I do not care that you have problems! You have to handle them on your own! Perhaps you need me, but do not expect any help with your situation!" Just like him, who expresses himself by "negative" behaviour, you express this statement with punishing him.

So, what can you do? I cannot give you a perfect answer. I do not know you, your son or your exact situation. I would recommend to talk to your son. Discuss with him WHY he behaves like he does. Do not insist that your perspective/opinion is the only right (this is important)! Let him talk, let him explain! Tell him that you want to help him in his situation and ASK HIM how you can do this. Again, it is important that you integrate him and his perspective in the solution. Otherwise it will not work. Giving and taking! Your experience (not the saying of other people! [see footnote]) and his view of the world should make the solution (best would be of course if he could give a solution that you can totally agree with).

Footnote: People say a lot of things in regard to how to "educate" a child (I have my own special opinion on this ^^). Most important thing is that YOU and YOUR SON are happy with each other and with the solution you agree on. If you try to fit into some vague expectations from other people (your parents, your grant-parents, your friends, etc.), your relationship with your son and your solution for your problem could work out but probably it will not. Because the solution and your relationship would not be YOU. (This is a little metaphysical but I hope you can get my point)

Answer (score 0):

The rules of etiquette apply to 5-yo children. Most know it instinctively, but others have to learn things the hard way.

Kindergarten in the US begins at 5. There are expectations. If a kid is inhibiting others' ability to learn, then there is a problem needing remedy.

Usually, the parent and teacher discuss the situation in depth. What works at home? Where are the deficits? What are the triggers? What are the warning signs?

Behavioral reward systems work better for most kids (and their teachers). But some kids really do need to learn the hard way. The school has a disciplinary guideline for the schoolteachers, but augmentation of a discipline plan at home is also necessary. The type of discipline you choose to use is beyond the scope of your question, but if you haven't tried "time out"s then you might want to start there.